# ¿Cómo insertar varios registros a una misma laravel y laravelcollective?

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

Quiero ingresar en una misma tabla varios registros, para ello utilizo este código en la vista:

```
<h3>Resultados</h3>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('descripcion_resultado', 'Resultado 1')}}
    {{Form::text('descripcion_resultado', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('descripcion_resultado', 'Resultado 2')}}
    {{Form::text('descripcion_resultado', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
</div>
```

este es mi controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $resultado = Resultado::create($request->all());    

        return 'resultados añadidos con éxito';
    }
```

Pero el problema está en que no me guarda los dos registro si no que guarda solo uno (el ultimo)

Comment: ¿La tabla solo tiene un campo?

Comment: solo tiene el campo id que es autoincremental y el campo de descripción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza un array en el nombre del campo, y luego iteras sobre esta, algo así:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('descripcion_resultado[]', 'Resultado 1')}}
    {{Form::text('descripcion_resultado[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('descripcion_resultado[]', 'Resultado 2')}}
    {{Form::text('descripcion_resultado[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}

</div>
```

En el controlador utilizas el método create():

```
public function store(Request $request){

    foreach ($request->description_resultado as $resultado) {
        Resultado::create(['description_resultado' => $resultado]); 
    }



    return 'resultados añadidos con éxito';
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, pero me aparece 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::createMany()

Comment: Perdón, mi error, createMany es para las relaciones, revisa mi edición.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funcionó muy bien tu solución, gracias!

Comment: @Talked Ojo con los `id` de los `inputs` y los `for` de los `labels`. Es probable que el código HTML no sea correcto ya que todos los campos tienen el mismo `name="descripcion_resultado[]"` y es a partir de eso que LaravelCollective genera los ids. Probablemente tengas que definir a mano el `id` de los `inputs`. Clickea en el 2do label y fijate si no te selecciona el primer input.